# Idiom Many go out for wool and come home shorn

Tags: idioms, proverbs

We've got a saying in Spain:

> ir por lana, volver trasquilado

I've found that in English already exists a similar proverb:

> Many go out for wool and come home shorn

whose [meaning](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803124704101) is also [similar](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/Ficha.aspx?Par=58828&Lng=0)

> many who seek to better themselves or make themselves rich, end by
>   losing what they already have.

But I'm not certain that the two of them share the following nuance. In Spanish it's applied also to

> Alude a quien fue a ofender y volvió ofendido

Let me adapt and translate

> The one who try to offend you, ends offending himself.

**Offend**, meaning in this case, that someone tries to demonstrate that you are wrong or that you are stupid but at the end he stands corrected or definitively showing that he is the stupid one.

Another saying in Spanish that reflects this meaning is

> Le salió el tiro por la culata / His gun backfired

Is correct the use of **Many go out for wool and come home shorn** in this case?
Are there any other idioms for this case?

Comment: His gun backfired **is** the expression for that! ;)

Comment: Related: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+biter+bit; more generally: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/what_goes_around_comes_around.

Comment: @userr2684291 The first one fits [Please, include it as answer] but not the second, in my opinion. "What goes around comes around" seems to imply that someone has accomplished to do harm and karma later punished him. We are talking that he couldn't do harm in the first place.

Comment: *What goes around comes around* describes the principle that says if you do good things, good things will happen to you; but also if you do bad things, bad things will happen to you. There are also proverbs borrowed from the Bible that describe what you want, but I don't know how common they are (I've never really heard them used). E.g., [*Malice backfires; spite boomerangs*](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs+26%3A27-28&version=MSG), or [*Whoever digs a pit will fall into it; if someone rolls a stone, it will roll back on them*](http://biblehub.com/proverbs/26-27.htm).

Comment: The famous line from Shakespeare:  "hoist with his own petard" applies to your "offend" scenario.

Comment: @userr2684291 But almost all these proverbs lack the sense of immeadiacy that I'm looking for. They seem to establish that if you do bads things, someday you will be punished somehow. Also, I'm not a religious person, I'm looking for something not related with churchs or bibles. Thanks all the same!

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Good one!

Comment: @RubioRic That's why they're proverbs and not really idioms, and that's why I'm posting them in a comment.

Comment: Here's what https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/bible-phrases-sayings.html says about the Bible and its influence on English: "The King James Version of the Bible has been enormously influential in the development of the English language. It ranks with the complete works of Shakespeare and the Oxford English Dictionary as one of the cornerstones of the recorded language. After Shakespeare, the King James, or Authorized, Version of the Bible is the most common source of phrases in English." You don't have to be religious to use the idioms listed there either.

Comment: @MaulikV I've been searching a bit and the idiom is just "backfire", isn't it? https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/backfire I think that "His gun backfired" is not used as a complete expression in English

Comment: @userr2684291 I have just realized ... "spite boomerangs". Boomerangs? In the Bible? Thought about it. And I'm not sure about backfire either. ;-P

Comment: @RubioRic The two quotes I gave there are merely different translations of the same thing; the former being obviously more modern.

Comment: @userr2684291 Adapted more than translated then. No offense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me compile some of the suggestions that appear in the comments above.

**[backfire (on someone)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/backfire)**

> [to cause harm to someone or something] to harm the person who runs the
>   scheme

@MalikV suggested that **his gun backfired** can be used but I have found no evidence of its usage.

[**the biter bit**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+biter+bit) suggested by @userr2684291

> the person who wanted to do harm, cheat somebody, etc., has harm done
>   to them, is cheated

**[hoist with his own petard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoist_with_his_own_petard)** suggested by @Tᴚoɯɐuo and taken from Hamlet by Shakespeare

> to cause the bomb maker to be blown up with his own bomb

**This last one is my favourite so far**. I'm marking this post as answer but the credit should go to @Tᴚoɯɐuo

Comment: If you like *hoist with his own petard,* you may like this more - *dig your own grave!* So, it goes like - by insulting others, he was digging his own grave.

Comment: @MaulikV I already knew that one. A great one, but it somehow lacks the sense of trying to harm others. From Oxford Dictionary: "to do something that causes you harm"

Answer (score 1):

One idiom in the same vain as your two expressions that I can think of at the moment would be [**the joke is on somebody**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/joke-is-on-sb):

> If you say that the joke is on a particular person, you mean that that person has tried to make someone else look silly but has made himself or herself look silly instead.

Moreover, it's also a common expression. What I mean by that is that it's not only found in dictionaries. You will actually hear somebody use it at some point if you listen to native English speakers speak long enough.

Comment: It might be worth adding that this phrase is almost always used with pronouns. I've heard plenty of people say, "The joke's on him!" but I don't know if I've ever heard anyone say, "The joke's on George!"